Remove delay after entering a wrong password
It's possible to remove 3s delay when entering wrong password?
Example in:
su -

command?
I've try to configure pam_unix and su module but it doesn'to work.
My /etc/pam.d/system-auth file:
#%PAM-1.0

#auth       required                    pam_faillock.so      preauth
# Optionally use requisite above if you do not want to prompt for the password on locked accounts.

-auth      [success=2 default=ignore]  pam_systemd_home.so
auth       [success=1 default=bad]     pam_unix.so          try_first_pass nullok nodelay
#auth       [default=die]               pam_faillock.so      authfail
auth       optional                    pam_permit.so
auth       required                    pam_env.so
#auth       required                    pam_faillock.so      authsucc
# If you drop the above call to pam_faillock.so the lock will be done also on non-consecutive authentication failures.

-account   [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_systemd_home.so
account    required                    pam_unix.so
account    optional                    pam_permit.so
account    required                    pam_time.so

-password  [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_systemd_home.so
password   required                    pam_unix.so          try_first_pass nullok shadow
password   optional                    pam_permit.so

-session   optional                    pam_systemd_home.so
session    required                    pam_limits.so
session    required                    pam_unix.so
session    optional                    pam_permit.so

My /etc/pam.d/su file:
#%PAM-1.0
auth            sufficient      pam_rootok.so
#Uncomment the following line to implicitly trust users in the "wheel" group.
#auth           sufficient      pam_wheel.so trust use_uid
#Uncomment the following line to require a user to be in the "wheel" group.
#auth           required        pam_wheel.so use_uid
auth            required        pam_unix.so nodelay
account         required        pam_unix.so
session         required        pam_unix.so
password        include         system-auth

When i type a wrong pass, there are 2,3 sec of delay:
[myuser@myhost ~]$ time su -
Password: 
su: Authentication failed

real    0m3,265s
user    0m0,008s
sys     0m0,008s

Bug or wrong pam config?
Thanks to all
My Manjaro info:
Operating System: Manjaro Linux 
KDE Plasma Version: 6.0.4
KDE Frameworks Version: 6.1.0
Qt Version: 6.7.0
Kernel Version: 6.9.0-MANJARO (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11


Cicoria67 if you would like to get the benefit of the +1 and the ✔ for the answer, please do copy and paste it to your own answer. You'll be able to accept it tomorrow (I think). The community answer can then be deleted, leaving just yours

I was editing the wrong pam.d file!
su - setting was in the /etc/pam.d/su-l file!
I’ve add nodelay in this line:
...
auth            required        pam_unix.so nodelay
...

